# Passing states between components in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am wondering the best way to tackle this problem.

I intend to create a state in the parent component of my application, pass the set state to a component that holds the button (sibling A), and the value to another component where it will be displayed and updated (sibling B). I have a rough idea of how to do this, but ultimately I am lost and am seeking direction. Thank you!

My parent component is as follows

```
  //playlist state
  const [playlistItem, setPlaylistItem] = useState()
  const mainCards = Data.map(card => {
    return(
      <MainCard 
          key={card.id}
          id={card.id}
          image={card.url}
          title={card.title}
          playbutton={card.playbutton}
          addbutton={card.addbutton}
          playlistState={setPlaylistItem}
      />
    )
  })
  const sideCards = SideData.map(card => {
    return(
      <SideCard 
        image={card.sideurl}
        key={card.id}
        title={card.sidetitle}
        playbutton={card.playbutton}
        addbutton={card.addbutton}
        playlistItem={playlistItem}
      />
    )
  })
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log("main cards" + mainCards[0])}
      {console.log("side cards" + sideCards.sidetitle)}
      
      <Navbar />
      <Header />
      <Playlist />
      <CardContainer />
      <div className="maincards">
          {mainCards}
      </div> 
      <div className="sidecards">
        {sideCards}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Sibling A

```
    const handleAdd = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="mainCardObject">
                <div className="cardObj">
                    <img src={props.image} className ="mainCardImage"/>
                    <img src={props.playbutton} className="playbutton"/>
                    <img src={props.addbutton} onClick={() => handleAdd(props.id)} className="addbutton" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

Sibling B

```
function Playlist(props){
    return(
        <div className="playlistContainer">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass both getter and setter as parameters, and use them normally in your components:

**Sibling A**

```js
const handleAdd = (id) => {
  //your logic
  props.playlistState(prevValue => [])
}
```

**Sibling B**

```js
return (
  <div className="playlistContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>
      {props.playlistItem}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
)
```

You can also create a function in your parent component, using set state, and pass this function as a parameter to your component:

**Parent**

```js
const addPlayListItem = (playListItem) => {
  setPlaylistItem(prev => [...prev, playListItem])
}

return (
  <SiblingA
    addPlayListItem={addPlayListItem}
  />
)
```

**Sibling A**

```js
function MainCard(props) {
  const handleAdd = () => {
    //your logic
    props.addPlayListItem({ name: 'rock', title: 'Foo Fighters', year: 2011 })
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={props.addbutton} onClick={handleAdd} className="addbutton" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sibling A:

```html
const handleAdd = (id) => {
        props.playlistState((prev) => ([...prev, id]))
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).